# Why doesn't Rails pick up my custom mail delivery method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I defined a custom delivery method, and load it in an initializer:

```
ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :custom, CustomDelivery
```

I then added `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :custom` to both development.rb and production.rb.

But when I want to send an e-mail

```
UserMailer.authorize(user).deliver
```

It fails with something related to SMTP (`ArgumentError: A sender (Return-Path, Sender or From) required to send a message
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:99:in deliver!'`) – which I **don't** want to use.

Why is it not picking up the custom delivery method?

UPDATE:
When I try from the console, I notice the following:

```
irb(main):019:0> UserMailer.delivery_method
=> :custom

irb(main):020:0> UserMailer.authorize(user).delivery_method 
=> #<Mail::SMTP:0x00000100bdc738 @settings={:address=>"localhost", :port=>25, :domain=>"localhost.localdomain", :user_name=>nil, :password=>nil, :authentication=>nil, :enable_starttls_auto=>true, :openssl_verify_mode=>nil, :ssl=>nil, :tls=>nil}>
```

(Btw I searched for "SMTP" in my project and there are 0 occurrences)

Comment: Any luck with this? I want to write a custom delivery_method to use the SendGrid API

Answer (score 2):

Configure the action_mailer delivery_method with your custom delivery class:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = MyCustomDelivery
```

That class should implement a deliver! instance method that takes an instance of the `Mail` gem. Something like this:

```
class MyCustomDelivery
  def deliver!(mail)
    puts "MAIL FROM: #{mail.from}"
    puts "RCPT TO: #{mail.to}"
    puts "DATA: #{mail.to_s}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you configured SMTP via `environment.rb` ? Here is how mine looks like.

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :domain          => 'gmail.com',
  :address         => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port            => 587,
  :tls             => true,
  :authentication  => :plain,
  :charset         => 'utf-8',
  :user_name       => ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME'],
  :password        => ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD'],
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```